# Add User session infomation to HTTPContext

Tags: asp.net, session, usersession

I am Having a User Class now i want to add that class to HTTPContext object so that each time i send a request I don't have to validate it

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET has several state management approaches - you need to choose the one most suitable to your need, and then store your validated user credentials once only.

If you have a single server setup, and can't see the need for multiple servers / a web farm in the future, you could consider using [ASP.NET Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Session State uses in-process memory on the server - so if you are spreading requests to multiple servers, this approach won't work. You would then consider storing an authentication token in your database. You can have a mixture of the two - [storing session state in the database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604).

Lastly, you could consider using [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx), which simplifies the job of creating and managing users, authentication, and authorization.